In the ROS2 Foxy- "Managing large projects" Tutorial, I am confused as to how the second turtle with name turtle2 spawned
I was following the ROS2 Foxy Managing large projects tutorial and I am stuck trying to understand why the second turtle spawned in the turtlesim1 environment. From what I can see, there are calls to spawn two separate turtlesim environments with one turtle "mimicking" the other. However 3 turtles are spawned. Any guidance will be greatly appreciated.

Please edit your question to show the exact commands you're running so we can help you determine what you're doing differently than the tutorial.
